# how to add email background in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

I want to send an email to a user with a background and logo with a name.

How can I do this with PHP? Here is the code I have so far.

```
public function sendEmail($thisUser)
    {
        $general = GeneralSetting::first();

        $hh  = ['s_title'=>$general->title,'s_footer'=>$general->footer_bottom_text];

        $mail_val = [
              'email' => $thisUser['email'],
                'name' => $thisUser['name'],
                'g_email' => $general->email,
                'g_title' => $general->title,
                'subject' => 'Verify Account',
            ];
            Config::set('mail.driver','mail');
            Config::set('mail.from',$general->email);
            Config::set('mail.name',$general->title);
            Mail::send('auth.verify-email', ['email' =>$thisUser['email'] ,'verifyToken'=>$thisUser['verifyToken'],'site_title'=>$hh['s_title'],'site_footer'=>$hh['s_footer']], function ($m) use ($mail_val) {
                $m->from($mail_val['g_email'], $mail_val['g_title']);
                $m->to($mail_val['email'], $mail_val['name'])->subject($mail_val['subject']);
            });

    }
```

Comment: U want to send mail with ur logo and background ???

Answer (score 1):

You can add image in your email by using variable `$message->embed('PATH')` in your view.

```
$message->embed('path/to/image/');
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use template and add html and css

```
Mail::send(
                'emails.password_reset',
                $data,                    
                function($message) use ($data) {
                    $message->to(
                        $data['email'], 
                        $data['full_name'])->subject('Password Reset Instructions.');
                }
            );
```

And in view create emails/password_reset

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>

<body style="font-family: Arial; font-size: 12px;">
<div>
    your email body
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, Laravel 5.5 already have a blade template for easy mailing system. You may read it here (https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/mail). There are plenty of ways you can do, with a view and/or by markdown. But way back, like what you are using `Mail::send()`. You are passing a view `auth.verify-email`, in there you may edit your view file just by adding an inline style like `background-color: #222222`. You may go here (https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/) to see what styles are acceptable by email providers.

You may also consider your image located in the cloud with an `https` protocol so your logo and images may not compromise security measurements on the email providers like Gmail.

In case your image is not located on the internet, you might consider adding your logo to the email attachment.

Also some pointers you might reconsider:

- You might want to create another variable for your long array

  `['email' =>$thisUser['email'] ,'verifyToken'=>$thisUser['verifyToken'],'site_title'=>$hh['s_title'],'site_footer'=>$hh['s_footer']]`
- Fixing your indentions, there are a couple of plugins like automatic indention.
- Fixing your spaces.

Hope you have a great time sending emails. :)